# Compare N data sets, only output and save differences

Tags: sas

I need to compare (pairwise) observations in N data sets. All data sets have the same table, variable attributes. I care only if differences in observations are detected, and I need to know which two tables, and the specific differences. What's the most efficient way to do it? I have some thing below and I'd appreciate comments/suggestion.

I am currently using the following codes:

```
proc compare base = a compare = b 
outnoequal outbase outcomp outdif noprint out = a_b_out; 
run;
```

So for every data set a_b_out, I only care if it is not empty.  SAS log can produce NOTE for this. 
I am currently using macro to check if it is empty in each a_b_out, and conditionally output it to a permanent directory.

Is there a better (more efficient way)?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's a reasonable way to do it.  Put that in a macro, and have the macro both run the compare and check for the differences.

You can actually also use the system code after the PROC COMPARE is run to see what kind of difference was reported, if you want to; `&SYSINFO.` contains a value describing what kind of differences were reported - see for example [this paper](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/063-2012.pdf) for more information.  (Basically, it's a packed integer, with each bit being a flag indicating a difference - the 13th bit indicates a value difference, or 4096.